# Which tools can automate remote control functionality from web to mobile devices

Tags: automated-testing, mobile

I have application like to control mobile devices remotely from Web.

My Requirement is:

```
    1. Login to the webpage (WPF app)
    2. Enter Phone Number in the search field on launched webpage & Click "Connect"
    3. Then SMS would be received on mobile device & then our application would be launched and Established Remote control session with that Mobile device
    4. Once connection established, then we can control mobile devices from web
```

Our application similar to "Airdroid" android app

Controlling mobile devices (All OS devices) from Webpage. It is [WPF (xbap) app](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970060%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) not a mobile website, that is we can launch URL in IE Browser (sample URL: "http://***.com/web/WebConsole.xbap")

So how to automate this requirement & which tool can be suitable for this?. Could anyone please provide suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you testing a mobile website or a WPF app on a Windows Phone/Tablet? Requirement is unclear.

Comment: added some more description

Answer (score 1):

As you want to drive different technologies end-to-end I think not many solutions will work. The browser, the web-app to remotely control a mobile device and the device it self.

Have a look at the open-source [Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/) its one of test frameworks which can interact with any application as long as you can see it. It uses partial screenshots to interact with applications. Aslong as the user interface is stable and does not change a lot this could be a solid choice.

**update**:
With the extra information you added to the question its might be possible to automate up to the controlling of the mobile device with [MS Coded UI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286681%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), if you have Visual Studio Premium+ you can try to record a test and see how far you get.

Answer (score 0):

depending on what remote-control means and on network connectivity, look for web server app for [your platform]

I tried [i-jetty](https://code.google.com/p/i-jetty/) on Android.